# I have found this in a German newspaper: "Don't spring from the margin"

Tags: word-usage

A German newspaper has published this instruction at a swimming pool in Berlin.

> 1. *Spring* can also mean *jump*
> 2. *Margin* is certainly not the edge of a pool

I'd write

> Don't jump off the edge of the pool.

Is it really very bad English or is the original instruction intelligible?

Comment: Why would a *newspaper* instruct people at a public pool? My guess is it's an ad, and the wording is a deliberate pun; *margin* is also the white space bordering the text in written media, and *spring* can also mean "jump out at you" (be attention-grabbing). Maybe they're saying even small news items can sometimes be surprising? Were there any graphics or pictures accompanying the text?

Comment: I should have written:

Comment: It sounds like the paper just used this sign as an illustration of too-literal translation from one language to another. Similar signs with translations from (usually Asian) languages form a near-endless source of internet humour.

Comment: According to [this newspaper in German](http://www.bz-berlin.de/berlin/spandau/bei-englisch-kommen-die-baeder-ins-schwimmen), it really was an innocent error; Google Translate isn't perfect, so I'm not positive, but it sounds like the guy responsible for the sign sheepishly said "the devil is in the details, I guess". To answer your question: given the context [a swimming pool], yes, native speakers would have been able to guess what was intended, but you're right of course that the word choice is entirely unidiomatic.

Comment: According to the source that @DanBron linked to, the sign was not "an instruction published by a German newspaper", but indeed, a German newspaper having found a sign that was very badly translated into English. The fact that is it not correct is the exact reason that it's in the paper.

Comment: @oerkelens I think what's confusing us about the question is a legitimate but ambiguous deletion: "A German newspaper has published a [n image of] an instruction reading...".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about interpreting an obvious mangling of English as legitimate English usage.

Comment: @Dan Bron: "Google translate isn't perfect". Indeed it isn't — it translates the same sign as *Don't jump off the page.*

Comment: For reference, [a search for Chinglish](https://www.google.nl/#q=chinglish) will reveal examples form Chines instead of German. They are intended to be correct English, but they are _not_ examples of correct ENglish usage and do not need an explanation based on English itself. It's rather a matter of comparing English with the source language to understand where things went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[margin](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/margin) does have an English meaning (among many others) of edge.  *"An edge and the area immediately adjacent to it; a border."*

At most swimming pools (North America) you would see a simple "No Jumping, No Diving".

Perhaps this is an example of a too literal translation from German.

Following the most recent edits [Vartek/Leach] - Yes your sentence is fine.